# Can I develop Kivy application for iOS on Windows?

Tags: python, ios, windows, kivy

I am trying to build an iOS application using Kivy, is it possible to pack this application using  Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. It might be possible using a macOS virtual machine under Windows, but of course Apple make this difficult and probably forbid it.

If there are web services providing app build infrastructure then it may be possible to use them.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a linux VM on your Windows system and use BUILDOZER to make a full working iOS package with your kivy code.

Docs here: https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You can't package for iOS from a linux VM.

Comment: Really? I'm on a real Linux system and i work on android, but considering the buildozer.spec i think it's possible to package for iOS with buildozer. The issue is with Linux VM?